# need new cite-command: argument of \cite[#1] to be placed not after, but in the middle of shorttitle

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I want to `\cite[#1]{thebook}` a book (with a shorthand) with numbered paragraphs not in the form `shorthand, \pnfmt{#1}`, but simply `XEN~#1~\emph{TP}\,3`, where the shorthand is `XEN~\emph{TP}\,3` (with link to the bibliography).

I tried to create a new `xparse`-command `\THEBOOK`, which doesn't work.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass[paper=A6,landscape,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,sortlocale=de,language=english,%
            sorting=nyvt,backend=biber,hyperref=true,shorthandintro=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{shortbib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% what I've tried
\NewDocumentCommand{\XEN}{o}{\cite[#1]{Xenophanes:TP}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook]{citetitle}%
{\XEN{XEN~#1~\mkbibemph{TP}\,3}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook]{shorttitle}%
{\XEN{XEN~#1~\mkbibemph{TP}\,3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

I cite: \XEN[87] oder \XEN{87}

\smallskip
It should look like: XEN~87~\emph{TP}\,3 (with a hyperlink)

\nocite{*}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{shortbib.bib}
@Book{Xenophanes:TP,
      editor =   {Benedikt Strobel},
      options =      {useauthor=false, useeditor=true},
      title =    {Xenophanes von Kolophon},
      shorttitle =   {Xenophanes},
      langid =   {english},
      date =     2018,
      translator =   {Benedikt Strobel},
      annotator =    {Benedikt Strobel},
      series =   {Traditio Praesocratica},
      number =   3,
      publisher =    {Gruyter},
      location =     {Berlin},
      pagination =   {paragraph},
      shorthand =    {XEN\addnbspace\mkbibemph{TP}\addnbthinspace3}}
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

[image: new-cite-format]

Comment: Hi. I don't have a solution right now. But with `DeclareFieldFormat` you only change the *formatting* of the printed `entryfield`. This field, in your case `shorthand`, is presumably inserted as fixed string. It may be possible to alter it with some kind of RegEx or similar. But maybe rather in one of the additional output files created by the `latex` and `biber` runs.

Comment: you probably should insert into the shorthand some command that can be changed on the fly, e.g. `shorthand =    {XEN\addnbspace\XENpar\mkbibemph{TP}\addnbthinspace3}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am nearly there. It now reads

`shorthand =  {XEN\addnbspace\printfield{postnote}~\mkbibemph{TP}\addnbthinspace3}`

The remains only one problem:

The `postnote` is printed twice: In the shorthand AND after the shorthand.

Comment: This is all but elegant, bit it works:
```\DeclareCiteCommand{\Xencite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}
    \switchATAY{citetitle:AT}{citeyear}}
  {}
  {}```